# ImageView siempre null por fragment

Tags: fragment, android-imageview

Quiero cambiar en la app el fragment de settings y quiero empezar por la imagen del usuario que es el cuadro de abajo.

en el onCreate

```
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child( "Users" ).child( uiD );

    mDatabase.addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            users = dataSnapshot.getValue( User.class );

            url=users.getAvatar();

            url();
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(final DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    } );
```

y luego el método donde imageview siempre me da null. Comentar que todo esto lo hago en la activity principal y no en el Fragment. Este mismo codigo me funciona en otra activity asi que supongo que me hara falta algo por el tema del fragment

```
public void url(){
    if(imageview!=null){
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(url)
                .into(imageview);  
    }
    Toast.makeText( context, "ImagenSettings NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Al final di con la solución, simplemente era declarandolo todo en el fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View vistas=inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false );
    imagephotosettings=vistas.findViewById( R.id.photoSettings );
    nameUser=vistas.findViewById( R.id.buttonUser);

    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    user = auth.getCurrentUser();

    DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child( "Users" ).child( user.getUid() );

    mDatabase.addValueEventListener( new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


            users = dataSnapshot.getValue( User.class );

            url=users.getAvatar();

            nameUser.setText(user.getDisplayName());

            url();//foto evento
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(final DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    } );




    return vistas;

}

public void url(){
    if(imagephotosettings!=null){
        Glide.with(this)
                .load(url)
                .into(imagephotosettings);
    }
    //Toast.makeText( , "ImagenSettings NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
}
```